# PowerShell Usage - File Upload Directory

Tags: powershell

I am hoping to get some assistance on PowerShell usage for HTTPS file upload. My current task to automate the copying of a directory of PDF file from a local network path to a HTTPS:// website. Whilst I have a local account on the web server, I have an issue with file upload and recursing the list all PDF's.

I tried `Invoke-RestMethod -URI`

```
$sourceFilePath = Get-ChildItem "\\DFS-Netwrok\PDF" -Recurse -Include *.pdf
$siteAddress = "https://contoso.com/PDF"; 
$urlDest = "{0}/{1}" -f ($siteAddress, "*.pdf"); 
$UserName = "UserName" 
$Password = "Password" 

function uploadFile() { 
    Param ([string] $sourceFilePath, 
             [string] $siteAddress , 
             [string] $urlDest,
             [string] $UserName, 
             [string] $Password) 
    $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
    $webClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($UserName,$Password);

     ("*** Uploading {0} file to {1} ***" -f ($sourceFilePath, $siteAddress) ) | write-host -ForegroundColor Green 

    $webClient.UploadFile($urlDest, "PUT", $sourceFilePath); 

    $httpresponse = $httprequest.GetResponse() 
} 

Upload-File -File $SourceFilePath -URI $SiteAddress -Dest $URLDest -Username $MyUsername -Password $MyPassword
```

Currently I get error on `Upload-File`.

I am happy to convert to any code which can provide the above task, list PDF from internal path connect to website with User/Pass and upload all PDF from local Directory. I can confirm the account can connect and has correct permissions on the destination website URL.

I am also looking at this example with error "Forbidden":

```
$Dir="\\Netwrok\Path"
$Url = "https://Website/PDF"
$user = "User"
$pass = "Password"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)

foreach($item in (dir $Dir "*.pdf"))
{ 
    "Uploading $item..."
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($Url+$item.Name) 
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)  
}
```

Returns error:

> Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server 
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
>   At line:16 char:22
>   +                      $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)
>   +                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Comment: Iam also looking more like this but also fails with : " Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server 
returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Comment: 403 is access problem. Maybe try this app called Postman. I strongly suspect the issue is with how the website wants your credentials. You are currently supplying it as basic auth. Try some others. The app can help you do that.

Comment: Could you provide me an example of use going through MS but jsut show switches, sorry not that advanced in PS yet.

Comment: I don't know what else to give you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5n07Ybz7yI
once you have the auth figured out, you can look up how to create a credential object in that authentication format.

Comment: I have also tried;

$Dir="\\Netwrok\Path"
$Url = "https://website.com/Files"
$user = "UserName"
$pass = "Pasword"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)

foreach($item in (dir $Dir "*.pdf"))
{ 
    "Uploading $item..."
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($Url+$item.Name) 
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)  
}

But still gives error in process;

Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" arguments : "The Remote server returned a error: (403) Fordbidden.

Comment: The strange part is in Batch it works fine with following;

net use y: https://website.com/Path /user:UserName Passowrd && move /y "\\Server\Path" "Y:\" && net use y: /delete

Comment: Sorry unable to uplaod code in the code box as now no longer lets me use aska  question says formatting wrong using correct box and no control seen in browser now.