# File Upload PowerShell Usage

Tags: powershell

Trying to cover the following into powershell with no sucess;

Active Batch Code:

```
net use y: https://website.com/Path /user:UserName Passowrd && move /y "\\Server\Path" "Y:\" && net use y: /delete
```

Would like to migrate to Powershell with simple task, I would have thought.

I have tired the following but always get argument errors on either fileupload or Invoke Webrequest. I am just trying to move some PDF internally to Web Host on https://website/folder

I have also Tried;

No longer can show code as site says error when submit question

Any suggestions? I can not understand the Auth, but the current job requires none other than Username and Password more usage and testing found here [Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420397/powershell-usage-file-upload-directory?noredirect=1#comment99442769_56420397://)

Comment: To many charector to post code when i Try says formatting error using the Code Button too ?

Comment: please, post the powershell code you tried & the error text - all of it - so that folks can make reasonable guess about what went wrong. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

`New-PSDrive -Name a -PSProvider FileSystem  -Root C:\Temp\ ;`
`Copy-Item -Path D:\a.txt -Destination a:\ ;`

`ls C:\Temp\a.txt`
`Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name`
`----                -------------         ------ ----`
`-a----         7/2/2019  12:20 PM              0 a.txt`

`Remove-PSDrive a`

For credentials provide `-credentials (@new-psdrive)` when attempting to access remote locations